# launch URL in Flet

Tags: python, flutter, flet

I'm using [Flet](https://flet.dev/) and I want for my app to launch a link when clicking on a button.

According to the docs, I can use [`launch_url`](https://flet.dev/docs/controls/page/#launch_urlurl) method. But when I tried, I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-6 (open_repo):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Iqmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Iqmal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\Iqmal\Documents\Python Projects\flet-hello\main.py", line 58, in open_repo
    ft.page.launch_url('https://github.com/iqfareez/flet-hello')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'launch_url'
```

### Code

```py
import flet as ft


def main(page: ft.Page):

    page.padding = ft.Padding(20, 35, 20, 20)
    page.theme_mode = ft.ThemeMode.LIGHT

    appbar = ft.AppBar(
        title=ft.Text(value="Flutter using Flet"),
        bgcolor=ft.colors.BLUE,
        color=ft.colors.WHITE,
        actions=[ft.IconButton(icon=ft.icons.CODE, on_click=open_repo)])

    page.controls.append(appbar)

    page.update()


def open_repo(e):
    ft.page.launch_url('https://github.com/iqfareez/flet-hello')


ft.app(target=main, assets_dir='assets')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I 'solved' this issue by moving the `open_repo()` function inside the `main()` function block. Now, the link can be opened on a browser when clicked. Example:

```py
def main(page: ft.Page):

    def open_repo(e):
        page.launch_url('https://github.com/iqfareez/flet-hello')

    appbar = ft.AppBar(
        title=ft.Text(value="Flutter using Flet"),
        bgcolor=ft.colors.BLUE,
        color=ft.colors.WHITE,
        actions=[ft.IconButton(icon=ft.icons.CODE, on_click=open_repo)])

    # code truncated for clarity
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/iqfareez/flet-hello/blob/bdde77f8c6d59e39f7a5dc25a70da7961d576162/main.py#L13L14).

Answer (score -2):

From what I'm seeing here and the errors you're getting it's just possible you might have a problem with the installation of Flet. Try installing running in a virtual environment and see if it changes.

Good Luck

Comment: should be a comment

Comment: It is not related to the Flet installation or anything. More like python.